# nRF24L01 : transmission fail when receiver is connected in Serial

Tags: serial, nrf24l01+

I have two Arduino Nano communication with radio.
One is a transmitter and send simple message :

```
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>


//RADIO RF24 PINS
#define RF_CE    7
#define RF_CSN   8

//Radio
RF24 radio(RF_CE,RF_CSN);
const byte address[6] = "00001";

//Communication structure
struct Data {
  long type;
  float value;
} data;


/**************************************************************************/
/*
    Displays some basic information on this sensor from the unified
    sensor API sensor_t type (see Adafruit_Sensor for more information)
*/
/**************************************************************************/

void initRadio() {
  radio.begin();
  radio.setRetries(15, 15);
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.openWritingPipe(address);
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Set delay between sensor readings based on sensor details.
    initRadio();
}

void sendMessage(long type, float value){
  Serial.println("sendMessage");
  data.type = type;
  data.value = value;
  if(radio.write(&data, sizeof(Data))){
    Serial.println("Send SUCCESS");
  }else {
    Serial.println("Send FAIL");
  }
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  // Delay between measurements.
    delay(1000);

    sendMessage(0, 20.10);
    sendMessage(1, 45.3);
    sendMessage(2, 1033);

}
```

The other is a receiver and get the message from the transmitter Arduino and send message with Serial via USB to a computer :

```
#include <SPI.h>

#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <printf.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <RF24_config.h>

#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define RF_CE    7
#define RF_CSN   8

//Radio RF24
RF24 radio(RF_CE,RF_CSN);
const byte address[6] = "00001";

//JSON
const int capacity = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(8);

//Communication structure
struct Data {
  long type;
  float value;
} data;


long previousMillis = 0;
long interval = 3000;  
bool refresh = false;


void sendValue(String source, String type, float value) {
  DynamicJsonDocument doc(capacity);
  doc["type_message"] = "measure";
  doc["source_id"] = source;
  doc["value_type"] = type;
  doc["value"] = value;
  Serial.write(0x11);
  serializeJsonPretty(doc, Serial);
  Serial.write(0x12);
  Serial.println("");
  doc.clear();
}

void initRadio() {
    radio.begin();
    radio.setRetries(15, 15);
    radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
    radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_LOW);
    radio.startListening();
}

void readRadio(){
  if(radio.available()){
    while(radio.available()) {
      radio.read(&data, sizeof(data));
      Serial.print("type:");
      Serial.print(data.type);
      Serial.print("value:");
      Serial.println(data.value);
      sendValue("remote", "test_radio", data.value);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //Init RF24 Radio
  initRadio();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if(currentMillis - previousMillis > interval) {
    // save the last time you blinked the LED
    previousMillis = currentMillis;  
    float humidity = 45.60;
    float temperature = 21.30f;
    sendValue("local", "humidity", humidity);
    sendValue("local", "temperature", temperature);
  }
  readRadio();

}
```

The issue that I have is that **when I connect my computer via the Serial port COM to the receiver, every radio message sent by the transmitter fail**. But before I connect to the receiver, the messages sent by the transmitter are in success.

I don't know what can cause this issue.

Comment: does the RF24L01 use an UART for its serial interface?

Comment: @jsotola, it is SPI